# What does the number in mediumint(10) denote?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm creating a table in  MySql and I came across columns with datatype as mediumint followed by a number in parenthesis. What does this number denote?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html says that unsigned mediumint can take a max value of 16777215, so how does it differ if  have columns with different sizes mediumint(6) or mediumint(10) ?

Comment: read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html. Here you have answer for your question

Answer (score 0):

I suppose here in an answer:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

so difference is only in formatting output, nothing else...